# Asp.net How do i delete objects with One To Many using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following tables team and player where their are many players per team based on teamId being a guid. As you can see the first row in the team table with guid of empty i no its just a test has two records based on teamID in the players table

[image]

My Main question using entity framework how would i delete the team and the player in one go with entity framework

[image]

As you can see the frist record

So in my team grid I was just doing the following but as you see this is only grabbing the team object. Obv I could just hit out at the players object first and delete them first.

```
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {

            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());
             team  _team= _dal.GetTeamByTeamId (strId);


            _dal.SoccerEntities.teams.DeleteObject(team);


        }
```

This is my GetTeamByTeamId function

```
    public team GetTeamByTeamId(Guid  teamId)
         {
        try
        {
            if (teamId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                team _team = new team();

                return _team;
            }
            else
            {
                var q = SoccerEntities.teams.Where(p => p.id == teamId);

                if (q == null)
                    throw new EntityContextException(string.Format("A team could not be found {0}!", teamId));
                else
                    return q.ToList()[0];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetTeamByTeamId failed.", ex);
        }




    }
```

This is asp.net by the way

**Edits**

I tried rankins suggesiton but have a an error on compile

> Error 36  'soccerCmsDal.team' does not contain a definition for 'players' and no extension method 'players' accepting a first argument of type 'soccerCmsDal.team' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\UniteCms\BackDoor\teams\default.aspx.cs   38  54  UniteCms

**My attempt to add a foreign key**
[image]

Ok now I have the foreign key setup its not working its giving me a null error

```
 {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());
            team _team = _dal.SoccerEntities.teams.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == strId);
            if (_team != null)
            {
                foreach (player _player in _team.players)
                {
                    _dal.SoccerEntities.players.DeleteObject(_player);
                }
                _dal.SoccerEntities.teams.DeleteObject(_team);
            }
            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();


        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling `cascading delete`? (I thought this was enabled by default)

Comment: @Stefan pleae see my edits

Comment: If the selected `_team` from @Rakin's answer contains the player you can also loop the collection and delete them one by one. Don't use `foreach` though because that might throw an exception stating that the collection has changed. (there must be something like: `_team.players`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());
            team _team = _dal.SoccerEntities.teams.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == strId);
            if (_team != null)
            {

                 if( _team.players!= null &&  _team.players.Count>0)
                 { var _palayers = _team.players.ToList();
                    foreach (player _player in _palayers )
                    {
                        _dal.SoccerEntities.players.DeleteObject(_player);
                    }
                 }
                _dal.SoccerEntities.teams.DeleteObject(_team);
            }
            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: please explain how doing a for each is effiennt what if 100 records would it be quick

Comment: I also have an error says Error 36 'soccerCmsDal.team' does not contain a definition for 'players' and no extension method 'players' accepting a first argument of type 'soccerCmsDal.team' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\new code\UniteCms\UniteCms\UniteCms\BackDoor\teams\default.aspx.cs 38 54 UniteCms

Comment: did you set foreign key for column teamid ?

Comment: i tried to but it sayed that i couldnt cause teamId was not unqiue but in my case teamId would be the same ??

Comment: can you explain the foreign key i screenshoted how i was doing it in case i did it wrong

Comment: @Rankin Im using ef5 and it says it dont contain a definiation for RemoveRange

Comment: @kymberly you were trying to set foreign for team table. its not correct way . set for player table.

Comment: @Rankin ok that worked with the table but now im recieveing a null error some reason please see last edit

Comment: that works but now I have a futher issue off the fact i cant delete a single player easy cause their is now a foreign key on the table.